# What is the meaning of "The effort"?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

In "*Star Wars The Last Jedi (2017)*", Kylo Ren says to Rey through a telepathy:

> You'll bring Luke Skywalker to me. You're not doing this. **The effort**
>   would kill you.

I'm not sure what it means, actually. I see that line as more of a foreshadow to when Luke projects himself to Crait at the end of the film.

Comment: Indeed. He's saying that a mental connection like that requires too much Force energy for Kylo Ren to handle. Luke then subverts this by using that much energy x however many people are watching.

Comment: @Valorum That makes the quote seem like foreshadowing the consequences of Luke's much larger effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The energy exerted to create such a telepathic projection, not to mention the training/skill required to do so, is presumed to be far past the ability of Rey.

While it's not made clear, it might be assumed that the only people who could see either Ren or Rey's projections were each other. So for Luke to be able to generate a projection that everyone in the room and the battlefield could see would likely require far more energy than even the basic projection between the pair.